# How to send UDP packets from Windows to GNU Radio running on WSL

Tags: udp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am using GNU Radio 3.8 on Windows, executed from WSL. I want to send UDP packets from the Windows environment to a GNU Radio UDP Source block (that uses localhost 127.0.0.1). I know that the localhost 127.0.0.1 is virtualized in WSL, but I am not sure how I can send packets to it. I know that WSL creates a "virtual" network for Linux but I also don't know the actual IP of the GNU Radio UDP Source block and how to communicate with it (what address/port I should use).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: please don't use GR 3.8 for new projects. You can install an environment that comes with GNU Radio 3.10 with a few clicks [from our installing GR page](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=InstallingGR). If the Linux distro you use within WSL still ships GR 3.8: it might be time to update.

Comment: I don't know anything about GNU Radio but you can get the IP Address of the Windows side of WSL using `ipconfig /all` in windows cmd and look through the interfaces for the container NICs it should say WSL in the name. In the container you can also try `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. To get the Linux side will depend on your Linux distro but you can try `wsl -d {DISTRONAME} hostname -I`. If that doesn't work you can try `wsl -d {DISTRONAME} /bin/bash` and then run `ip a` or `ifconfig` to list the network interfaces. But again that will all depend on your Linux distro so your mileage may vary.